# Rxjava observable somtimes miss some item when the items are emtted in different threads

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

With "observeOn(Scheduler)", Rxjava observable seemes that somtimes miss some items when the items are emitted from different threads.

Here is the code

```
val subject = PublishSubject.create<String>()

subject
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe { x: String? -> println(x) }

val t1 = Thread { subject.onNext("1") }
val t2 = Thread { subject.onNext("2") }

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

What I expect is that console have to ALWAYS print like below

```
1
2
```

but sometimes result was only

```
1
```

or

```
2
```

Is there any reason about it?

In addition) If I remove "observeOn(Schedulers.io())", the result was same with my expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/subjects/PublishSubject.html) is not thread safe for its `onXXX` methods and you have to serialize access to it in some fashion. The simplest way is to apply `toSerialized()`:

> Calling onNext(Object), onError(Throwable) and onComplete() is required to be serialized (called from the same thread or called non-overlappingly from different threads through external means of serialization). The Subject.toSerialized() method available to all Subjects provides such serialization and also protects against reentrance (i.e., when a downstream Observer consuming this subject also wants to call onNext(Object) on this subject recursively).

```kotlin
val subject = PublishSubject.create<String>().toSerialized()
```